# Batch files "for" comand and importing variables from other files

Tags: variables, batch-file, import

I have config.txt file. In that file I typed this:

- number_1
- number_2
- number_3
- number_4

I want to be able to import the variables into a bat file and use them. I tried to do this with for command but I can't find on the internet enough help.

I came up with this:

[Here is code](http://wklej.org/id/1383957/)

but it's not working as I want. It is showing me only number_4 rest is just "ECHO is off"

Please help.
Sorry for my english

Comment: `tokens` mean `unit in this line`, not `linenumber`. You have only one token per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your example it's quite simple:

```
(for /l %%i in (1,1,4) do set /p "w%%i=" )<config.txt
```